# Does Dynamo IoC work with MonoTouch and MonoDroid?

Tags: dependency-injection, xamarin.ios, inversion-of-control, xamarin.android, unity-game-engine

I'm curious, out of all the possible C# .NET inversion of control solutions out there, if anyone has ever tried Dynamo IoC (http://www.dynamoioc.com/) and whether or not it works with projects designed for MonoTouch and MonoDroid?

While I am not explicitly using either MonoTouch or MonoDroid, I am using Unity 3D (http://www.unity3d.com). I expect that if  an IoC framework (e.g. Dynamo) works on MonoTouch and MonoDroid it will more likely than not also satisfy my needs with Unity 3D.

**NOTE:** I've been doing research on inversion of control containers, and their compatibility with MonoTouch, MonoDroid, etc. for a couple of days now; this questions does not come from laziness, but a lack of details I've found when doing my research specifically regarding Dynamo IOC and its compatibility with MonoTouch, MonoDroid, etc.

Comment: [Stackoverflow site is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937)

Comment: I've been researching IOC containers for about 2 days now, but have not found very much on Dynamo IOC beyond benchmarks citing its speed. I may have missed something when doing my searches, but I don't feel my question is inappropriate.

Comment: You're missing the point.  I'm not saying your'e being lazy.  I'm saying asking open ended question seeking comparisons of different products on the market is totally off-topic for this site.

Comment: I see your point, I've removed the sidebar and rephrased the question to be more pointed specifically asking only about Dnamo IoC and its compatibility with MonoTouch and MonoDroid. Thank you for the comment; I think that this question now more aptly meets the spirit of StackOverflow's question and answer system.

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer about DynamoIoC, but I have used TinyIoC and OpenNetCF IoC on MonoTouch and MonoDroid without problems.

- https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC
- http://ioc.codeplex.com/

Within MvvmCross I currently make use of a very limited set of the OpenNetCF functionality and that works across wp7, ios, droid and winrt.

Comment: I've been looking at TinyIoC and that is definitely on my radar. I hadn't heard about OpenNetCF.IoC before; I'll take a look at that as well. Thanks for the recommendations!

Comment: If it helps, the OpenNetCF team are long time hard-core Windows Mobile/WinCE coders - their code is very well established! I even used to be a paying customer a few years back.

Comment: We also heavily dogfood the OpenNETCF IoC library across apps that run in CF, Windows desktop, WinPhone, MonoDroid and MonoTouch. Those apps are continually being improved and extended, so IoC ends up being a active project.

Comment: TinyIoC works great on MonoDroid. You also get the bonus of TinyMessenger, which I've been using to implement quite a bit of service-like behaviour with less ceremony than some of the native MonoDroid infrastucture.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamo does not appear to be usable with C# projects targeting iOS platforms, via MonoTouch or Unity 3D.

I was able to find [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations) on Mono's limitations, courtesy of a few other questions and answers here on StackOverflow; after a more thorough review of Dynamo IoC's [code](https://github.com/MartinF/DynamoIOC) and a better understanding of what the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace entails, it looks like Dynamo is able to achieve most of its speed through the use of the dynamic expressions offered by Linq. It is my understanding that code using `System.Linq.Expressions` falls under the same category as dynamic code generation, thus rendering Dynamo IoC unusable for MonoTouch (and by proxy Unity 3D projects targeting iOS).

Comment: Just to check - have you actually tried running this on a real device with MonoTouch? If not, then please don't push this out there is an accepted answer and fact.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I'm just embarking on a MonoTouch project and I'm using [Munq.IocContainer](http://munq.codeplex.com/). Munq is a small DI framework that I've used previously in an ASP.NET MVC project and a Windows Mobile 6 application. Although it doesn't have the bells and whistles of the larger frameworks it is fast and easy to configure.</del>

Please ignore above. I started using Munq which was working very well in the simulator but failed horribly when I tried to deploy to an actual iPhone. This is because Munq JIT's some code which AFAIK is not ok in MonoTouch on iOS. I've gone back to [Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/) from which Munq is derived. Munq was actually intended for use in ASP.NET MVC3 so reverting to Funq also means there are no references to system.web that need to be removed.